# Copy address fields into billing address fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to copy the user's address into the billing address fields based on a checkbox value. But every time when the checkbox is checked only the last value of the input fields gets copied to the billing address section. And it is important not to use the ids because they are dynamically set.

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#veranstaltungsanmeldung_billing_address'); 

    checkbox.on('click', function(){
        if(checkbox.prop('checked')) {
            var srcValues = [];

            $(".address").each(function(){
                var srcValue = $(this).find('input[data-src]').val();
                srcValues.push(srcValue);
            });

            $.each(srcValues, function(index){
                $('.billing-address').find('input[data-dst]').val(srcValues[index]);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="{{ path('veranstaltungsanmeldungsubmit') }}/{{ danksagungsid }}" method="post"  id="veranstaltungsanmeldung" class="form-horizontal" role="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% if validationErrors is defined %}
    <div class="form-error">
        {{ validationErrors }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.anrede.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.anrede"|trans }}:{% if form.vorname.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.anrede, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.titel.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.titel"|trans }}:{% if form.titel.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.titel, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.vorname.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.vorname"|trans }}:{% if form.vorname.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.vorname, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.nachname.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.nachname"|trans }}:{% if form.nachname.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.nachname, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group address">
    <label for="{{ form.unternehmen.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.unternehmen"|trans }}:{% if form.unternehmen.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.unternehmen, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'data-src': 'company' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.funktion.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.funktion"|trans }}:{% if form.funktion.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.funktion, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group address">
    <label for="{{ form.strasse.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.strasse"|trans }}:{% if form.strasse.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.strasse, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'data-src': 'street' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.postleitzahl.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.plz"|trans }}:{% if form.postleitzahl.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{ form_widget(form.postleitzahl, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
    <label for="{{ form.ort.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1 control-label">{{ "form.ort"|trans }}:{% if form.ort.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-6">
        {{ form_widget(form.ort, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.land.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.land"|trans }}:{% if form.land.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.land, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.telefon.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.telefon"|trans }}:{% if form.telefon.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.telefon, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.e_mail.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.e_mail"|trans }}:{% if form.e_mail.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.e_mail, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>

{% if location.id != 3481794 %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.anmerkungen.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.anmerkungen"|trans }}:{% if form.anmerkungen.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ form_widget(form.anmerkungen, {
                'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
            })}}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

<div class="form-group"{% if not ez_field_value(content, 'show_billing_fields').bool or (location.id != 3486083 and location.id != 3486084) %} style="display: none;"{% endif %}>
    <label for="{{ form.billing_occupation.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.careercenter.billing_occupation.label"|trans }}:{% if form.billing_occupation.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.billing_occupation, {
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
        })}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group hide-legend">
    <label for="{{ form.freies_attribut.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        {{ form.freies_attribut.vars.label }}
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 select-list">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>{{ form.freies_attribut.vars.label }}</legend>
            {{ form_widget(form.freies_attribut) }}
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="checkbox billing-address-checkbox"{% if not ez_field_value(content, 'show_billing_fields').bool %} style="display: none;"{% endif %}>
    <label>
        {{ form_widget(form.billing_address) }} {{ "form.billing_address"|trans }}{% if form.billing_address.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}
    </label>
</div>

{% if location.id == 3481794 %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.anmerkungen.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-12 control-label">{{ "form.fbd_question"|trans }}:{% if form.anmerkungen.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            {{ form_widget(form.anmerkungen, {
                'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
            })}}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

<div class="event-billing-block"{% if not ez_field_value(content, 'show_billing_fields').bool %} style="display: none;"{% endif %}>
    <h4 class="mt20">Rechnungsadresse</h4>
    <div class="form-group billing-address">
        <label for="{{ form.billing_company.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.unternehmen"|trans }}:{% if form.billing_company.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ form_widget(form.billing_company, {
                'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'data-dst': 'company' }
            })}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group billing-address">
        <label for="{{ form.billing_street.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.street"|trans }}:{% if form.billing_street.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ form_widget(form.billing_street, {
                'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'data-dst': 'street' }
            })}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.billing_zip.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.zip"|trans }}:{% if form.billing_zip.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form_widget(form.billing_zip, {
                'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
            })}}
        </div>
        <label for="{{ form.billing_place.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1 control-label">{{ "form.place"|trans }}:{% if form.billing_place.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.billing_place, {
                'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
            })}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.billing_country.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ "form.country"|trans }}:{% if form.billing_country.vars.required == true %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ form_widget(form.billing_country, {
                'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }
            })}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would be nice if somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: add your html file also

Comment: updated :D template language is twig btw

Comment: Instead of doing `array.push`, you can use a string and append all the address values to it and instead of using `array.forEach`, directly assign the saved value to the new input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through `srcValues` array setting the `input[data-dst]` value to the array loop.

I mean, you are doing this:

```
var thisIsInputValue;
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array.forEach(function(value) {
    thisIsInputValue = value;
});
```

If you are looping through the array and setting the `thisIsInputValue` to the array value, it will have the last value assigned, just like this:

```
var thisIsInputValue;

thisIsInputValue = 1;
thisIsInputValue = 2;
thisIsInputValue = 3;
thisIsInputValue = 4;

// At this point, thisIsInputValue will be 4.
```

I don't know what you expect actually.

EDIT: Note that `thisIsInputValue` is your `$('.billing-address').find('input[data-dst]').val(srcValues[index]);`. You are simply resetting the value of `input[data-dst]`. Not concatenating.

EDIT2: Try this:

```
$(".address").each(function(){
    // Get the initial input
    var input = $(this).find('input[data-src]');
    // get the data-src value (as will be the thing that identifies the other input)
    var inputDataSrc = input.data("src");
    // get the input value
    var inputValue = input.val();

    // Get the billing input with the same data-src value
    var billingInput = $('.billing-address').find('input[data-dst="'+inputDataSrc+'"]');
    // Set the value
    billingInput.val(inputValue);
});
```

This is some kind of pseudocode written on-the-fly. Maybe don't works at first run but you get the idea. This is the way to go as the only thing that identifies the inputs is the `data-src` value.

Comment: I know that i'm overwriting the varaible but how to avoid this in a clean way?

Comment: What do you want to have as the value actually @StaXter? Some kind of copy from .addess to .billing-address?

Comment: Yes, i want to copy the .address values into the right .billing-address fields.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!